# Is it possible to boot from a USB flash drive on a Toshiba Tecra A2?

Tags: laptop, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

**Is it possible to boot a Toshiba Tecra A2 from a USB flash drive?**

BIOS shows no boot option for USB. I haven't yet found any way to do it, but I might be missing some option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which BIOS version is yours, but did you try to change your BIOS settings? I believe you can enter in your notebook's setup by [pressing F1](http://www.its.swin.edu.au/staff_services/procurement/manuals/ToshibaTecraA2.pdf) after it's turned on. Then check "boot devices" and see if "USB" is taking precedence from "Hard Disk" and other peripherals.

Comment: Unfortunately the pre-installed BIOS does not have any USB-options. That's part of the problem :-)

Comment: Do you know if this is the latest BIOS? Maybe upgrading you'll have USB options (I'm not sure about it, but newer BIOS can provide thos feature).

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the Tohshiba Tecra A2's motherboard does not support booting from USB devices. You may however circumvent this by installing a boot manager with USB support on a CD and booting from this medium instead.

One such boot manager, Plop, can be downloaded [here](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html).

Burn the .iso to a disc, boot from that and a menu will appear. Select 'USB' and voila.

[image: Plop main menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the settings and manually select a boot device bypressing one of the following keys while the computer is booting:
 press "U" to use usb